# App is crashed with Google maps SDK cocoapods in Xcode 9 and iOS 11

Tags: swift, google-maps, cocoapods, ios11, xcode9.2

i'm upgraded Google Maps SDK cocoapods to the latest version 2.6. but when i'm trying to run my app, it's crashed. it's happened in iOS 11 and Xcode 9.2.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Clean the project and the build by these two commands:

Clean Build: `Command + alt option + Shift + K`
Clean Project: `Command + Shift + K`

And Build your project again and it won't crash again.